# Get text by id from sql query

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have sql table 1 where I have also ID with value -1.

```
select id, art_1, art_2, art_3 from table1;

id  |  art_1  |  art_2 |  art_3
----|---------|--------|----------
-1  |    1    |    2   |   null
 1  |    0    |    0   |   null
...
```

Values in art_1 and art_2 where ID = -1 means title from table 2.

```
select id, title from art;

id    title
------------
1     car
2     toy
```

Now, I build dynamically asp table and I want get in `TableHeaderCell` **title** from **art_n**. I have no ideas, because the fields `art_n` are numeric.

```
Dim n As Integer = 3
For i As Integer = 1 To 7
    If IsNumeric(myDataReader("art_" & i.ToString)) Then
       trHeaderRow.Cells.Add(New TableHeaderCell)
       trHeaderRow.Cells(n + 1).Width = Unit.Pixel(100)
       trHeaderRow.Cells(n + 1).Text = myDataReader("art_" & i.ToString).ToString
       trHeaderRow.Cells(n + 1).CssClass = "example Text3"
       n += 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You should read both tables into a DataSet first.  Then use the value from art_1 or art_2 to look up the title in the art table.

Comment: can you show code example, please